# Port pthread_cond_broadcast to std::atomic

Tags: c++, atomic

Trying to understand all the in and out of std::atomic (lock-free operations in C++ 11).

I was wondering if an operation like this:

```
bool SomeClass::waitMyVariableToBeSet() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex);
    while (!MyVariableToBeSet) {
        r = pthread_cond_timedwait(&msCondVariableSet, &mMutex, &ts);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex);
}
```

AND

```
void SomeClass::setMyVariable(bool newVal) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutex);
    MyVariableToBeSet= newVal;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&msCondVariableSet);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutex);
}
```

Could be replace like this with std::atomic:

```
std::atomic<bool> MyVariableToBeSet;

bool SomeClass::waitMyVariableToBeSet() {
    uint someTimeOutCnt = 100;
    while (!MyVariableToBeSet.compare_exchange_strong(false, true) && SomeTimeCnt) {
         someTimeCnt--;
         std::this_thread::yield(); // no sure of this here
   }
}

void SomeClass::setMyVariable(bool newVal) {
    MyVariableToBeSet= newVal;
}
```

Comment: You have 2 case which are significantly different by functionality, how can you replace one with another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C++20 this can be implemented using new atomic [`wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait) and [`notify`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/notify_all) operations:

```
std::atomic<bool> MyVariableToBeSet;

bool SomeClass::waitMyVariableToBeSet() {
    MyVariableToBeSet.wait(false);
}

void SomeClass::setMyVariable(bool newVal) {
    MyVariableToBeSet = newVal;
    MyVariableToBeSet.notify_all();
}
```

Internally those will be implemented using a hash map of queues or using kernel APIs such as [`futex`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/futex), [`WaitOnAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress)/[`WakeByAddressAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-wakebyaddressall), [`_umtx_op`](https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=_UMTX_OP) when possible.

Before C++20 there is no direct equivalent and you have to use condition variables or platform-specific APIs directly.

Answer (score 0):

C++ 20 implemented the solution

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag

Otherwise, I believe a spinlock would be the compromise with all trade off that comes with it.